# Why are Facebook photo urls unprotected?

Tags: facebook, security, url, cookies

So I copy-pasted the URL of one of my photos from my Facebook (private profile), and sent it to someone.

And I can just link it [here](https://scontent.fclj2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/50917068_2175584162499706_6191154516339982336_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100&_nc_ht=scontent.fclj2-1.fna&oh=008491e06cefdc301d14e54945fef02c&oe=5D11267F) and it works for anyone, anyhwere, no matter if they are connected with me or not.

Why aren't photo URLs cookie-protected and why isn't this considered a security breach?

Comment: The URL that you shared contains the access token. Notice that if you try hitting the JPG url, you are rejected: https://scontent.fclj2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/50917068_2175584162499706_6191154516339982336_n.jpg - you need all the extra parameters.

Comment: Still, is it considered ok for it to be shareable like this with anyone?

Comment: Considering that it's not the "Facebook"-way of sharing photos, I don't see how it's considered bad practice when you're giving away a padlock with the key still in it.

Comment: If you accessed the image you could just save it and upload it somewhere else and then share that URL.

Comment: Hmm ok. I wanted to know what's considered "an issue" and what's not from a security POV and whether or not it would be safe to use this approach in my app

Comment: I would say it depends on how secure you want it to be. If you can secure it with a cookie, of course it's better. I believe AWS Buckets is using the same thing as Facebook but with a time limited token for instance.

Comment: I think in the Facebook case it's sufficient. The weakest link is the end user but it stops any scrapers from indexing all the images.